# How to declare a variable in a method as static (java)

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, static-methods, static-variables

I am creating an encryption/decryption program that uses multiple classes. I have one class that is the UI, and uses a JFrame form with a file selector, and another class that encrypts/decrypts the selected file. I am encountering a problem when I try to use the java.io.File variable declared in the UI class in the encryption class.

File selector code:

```
public static void actionEncrypt() {
    encrypt = true;
    int retVal = selectFile.showOpenDialog(null);
    if (retVal == selectFile.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        java.io.File file = selectFile.getSelectedFile();
        System.out.println(file);
        Crypt.encrypt();
    }
}
```

Variable declaration code:

```
public static boolean encrypt;
public static java.io.File file;
```

File reading code:

```
public static void encrypt() {
    System.out.println(MainUI.file);
    try {
        Scanner filescan = new Scanner(MainUI.file);
        int count = 0;
        while (filescan.hasNextLine()) {
            count++;
            filescan.nextLine();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File not found!");
    }
}
```

When I run this code, I get a `NullPointerException` because the value of the File variable while the file reading code is running is null. This is because it was declared as static in the variable declaration code, which overwrites the value that was declared in the method `actionEncrypt`. If I don't make the variable static, I get a `Cannot find symbol` when I try to access it from the other class. However, I cannot declare the variable as static within the method `actionEncrypt`, because it gives me an `illegal start of expression`. Does anyone know how to declare a variable in a method as static without hiding a field, or any other way to use the File variable in another class?

Thanks in advance,

Santiago

Comment: `"The variable must be static in order to be accessed from other classes."` -- this is wrong, so very wrong. Your variable should most definitely **not** be static. I'm not saying that static variables should never be used, and in fact there are many situations where they are quite helpful, but I am saying that this is not one of those situations. Instead if it must be accessible from other classes, make it an instance variable, and consider giving this class a getter method.

Comment: Show us a little bit more code, and we'll show you how to re-arrange it so you either do not need to use `static` variables, or ensure that initialization happens first.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels - Sorry, I didn't word it right. What I meant was that in these particular circumstances, the variable has to be static because or else I get a `Cannot find symbol` when trying to access it from the encryption class. I edited the question with more precise wording.

Comment: It sounds like you are using the class `MainUI` without instantiating it. In that case, you should have some code in the MainUI that initializes the variable `file`, before the encryption code calls it.

Comment: How do I initialize the variable `file`? Isn't it already initialized when it is set to the file selected?

Comment: Unless you wrote code to do that, it is not initialized. Show us the code where you think you are initializing it.

Comment: By the way, the method `actionEncrypt` is called from an ActionListener method. Perhaps this is the problem?

Comment: java.io.File file = selectFile.getSelectedFile(); Here you are hidding file static variable. So static file is not initialised.

Comment: @Santiago, See my answer. I am only guessing here because I do not have all your code.

Comment: You misunderstand me: this error, `Cannot find symbol` does not mean that you should make the variable static. It means likely that you need to access it with a proper *instance* and call the appropriate getter method. You will want to read a decent book on OOP programming and Java such as Bruce Eckels's "Thinking in Java" because you will need to break some dangerous preconceptions. In other words don't use a static modifier kludge when the correct solution is to fix the program's bad design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I see the error in your code.

Change the following line so that you initialize `MainUI.file` instead. Currently you are creating a local variable called `file` and initializing that one instead of `MainUI.file`, which is what you probably intended to initialize.

```
    java.io.File file = selectFile.getSelectedFile();
```

Replace it with.

```
    MainUI.file = selectFile.getSelectedFile();
```

Comment: So I am assuming that I add the replacement code into the encryption class?

Comment: @Santiago, Delete the first line, and put the second line exactly where the first line used to be.

Comment: Ok. I tried putting it in either class, and it works in both. Thanks for the help!